# history does not match with the model.fit() log, when using verbose = 1

Tags: verbose

I was training a functional API model, and my model is shown as below:
total number of data is 1094, and the train : valid : test ratio is 7: 2: 1.

```
def bonepool():
    bonepool_input = Input(shape = (1024, 256, 1))
    x = Conv2D(4, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(bonepool_input)
    x = Conv2D(4, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(2, strides = (2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(2, strides = (2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(2, strides = (2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same', strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(2, strides = (2, 2))(x)
    boonepool_output = Flatten()(x)
    return Model(bonepool_input, bonepool_output)
model_1 = bonepool()
model_2 = bonepool()
concate = average([model_1.output, model_2.output])
x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(concate)
x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
ensemble_model = Model([model_1.input, model_2.input], output)
```

precision, recall, f1score function was made by using keras.backend.
And I compiled my model like this, and checked the history after fitting the model. But something went wrong.

```
 opt = Adam(learning rate = 0.01)
 Class_wegiht = {0:4, 1:0.5}
 ensemble_model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy', precision, recall, f1score])
 hist = ensemble_model.fit(train, batch_size= BATCH_SIZE, epochs = 10, stepts_per_epoch = train__len__(), class_weight = Class_weight, validation_data = valid, validation_steps = valid.__len__(), verbose = 1)
```

result was (I deleted all the other relevant values)

Epoch 1/10
47/47 [========================================] loss : 0.1427, accuracy = 0.8765, ...

Epoch 2/10
47/47 [========================================] loss : 0.8736, accuracy = 0.3987, ...

Epoch 3/10
47/47 [========================================] loss : 0.1563, accuracy = 0.8655, ...

Epoch 4/10
47/47 [========================================] loss : 0.1125, accuracy = 0.8788, ...
.........

But when I printed the history,

```
hist.history['accuracy']
```

first four values were not as same as the log of model.fit()
it was like

[0.8211,
0.3712,
0.7764,
0.8853,
......]

And the same problem is applied to loss, f1score, recall, precision, valid_loss, valid_accuracy, valid_f1score, valid_recall,.... etc.

But when I changed verbose from 1 to 2, all the values of the model.fit() log were exactly same as hist.history.

Some say that model.fit() lacks the last_output, so there could be slight difference between model.fit() and history, but while I was my model, the difference between them sometimes went more than 3.0(loss was 4.2, while history['loss']of that epoch was just 1.2), and I think it's not a slight difference.

And if it is a problem between the average and last_output, then the model.fit() log while using verbose=0 and verbose=1 should have been different even when I use the Sequential model.
But when I use the sequential model instead of Functional model, the three values(model.fit log(verbose = 0), model.fit log (verbose = 1), hist.history) were exactly same.

So I suspect when using functional API, the result(accuracy, precision, recall, f1score, etc.) shown by verbose=1 is always different from that of verbose=2, and the history always matches with the latter, not the former.
Is it right? or if it is not, can someone tell me what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Your speculation seems right. The loss and other metrics you get from

```
hist.history
```

are averages over epoch. However, if you use verbose 1, the log (output prints) file might not match the history since they're being updated after each batch. What you need to trust would be:

```
hist.history
```

Bear in mind that the values for the training set are being calculated over epoch while the weights are being optimized this means the values related to the training set from the history might not match:

```
ensemble_model.evaluate(train)
```